# AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap); in appium is not working

Tags: selenium, appium

I am learning appium using Java and I am continuously resolving issues and here new issue has arisen. Please help me. I cant intialize android driver its giving me error. I am using eclipse, android studio and maven repository
Can someone guide me on this.

...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;


public class ClubHouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File appDir = new File("src");
                File f = new File(appDir, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
                DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
                cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "huzaifa");
                cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, f.getAbsolutePath());
                
                cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator");

                AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver =new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
            

    }

}
```

...
**pom file**
...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>clubHouse</groupId>
  <artifactId>clubHouse</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

<dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-beta</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUANX.png

Answer (score 1):

With appium version 8.0.0 AndroidElement is no longer available and AndroidDriver is no longer generic.

Change

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

to

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

You should also change DesiredCapabilities to UiAutomator2Options as it should no longer be used.

Maybe also check https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md for other changes.